# ISO Certification and Other details of Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, iso

One of my client is asking for ISO 27001 certification status, valid date and scope for Microsoft Azure. I ran my product on this cloud since last 3 years.
I Googled but nothing significant is found.
Have you dealt with this situation before? This is a European MNC and they have strict SAAS product onboarding process that cannot be skipped/gambled.
Please advise

Comment: First result when googling " Azure ISO 27001"

Comment: You can refer to [ISO/IEC 27001:2013 overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/compliance/offerings/offering-iso-27001), [ISO/IEC 27001:2013](https://www.iso27001security.com/html/27001.html) and [Details of the ISO 27001:2013 Regulatory Compliance built-in initiative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/iso-27001)

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I find the below mentioned link much helpful. https://servicetrust.microsoft.com/Documents/ComplianceReports?fbclid=IwAR3C6akySCNaOcRUbOA_jt3d7X3uDb7mXSSUW6IbtRyI28TtFHTjk0HHBGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to a Facebook group which is dedicated for Azure professionals and has 50k professionals.

I got this link there - https://servicetrust.microsoft.com/Documents/ComplianceReports?fbclid=IwAR3C6akySCNaOcRUbOA_jt3d7X3uDb7mXSSUW6IbtRyI28TtFHTjk0HHBGE

This link had all the documents. I wanted CSA Star, C5, 27001, 27013 and FedRAMP.

You just need to be smart enough to search for relevant certificates on this portal.